# Convert date and int time as datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column MyDate as date and TimeStart as int.
how can I convert the below image as date time in SQL like 2019-11-01 00:06

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? ...

Comment: i would like to use this in sql server

Comment: Okay. SQL Server is quite special when it comes to dates/times. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Oh no! 145 is supposed to be 1 x 60 + 45 minutes? I didn't notice this before. Why are you storing this like that? Either use a time column or store minutes, not some obfuscated number that has to be interpreted as two separate parts. And while we're at this, why do you have two columns at all? Why not a datetime `2019-11-01 00:06` in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't told us which DBMS you are using. In standard SQL you'd add n minutes thus:

```
<some_date> + <number_of_minutes> * interval '1' minute
```

(At least that's how I read the standard syntax, where the interval literal is defined as

```
<interval literal> ::= INTERVAL [ <sign> ] <interval string> <interval qualifier>
```

In your case:

```
select mydate + timestart * interval '1' minute from mytable;
```

Some DBMS may allow your column in place of the "interval string":

```
select mydate + interval timestart minute from mytable;
```

**UPDATE:** For SQL Server use

```
select dateadd(minute, timestart, mydate) from mytable;
```

**Another update:** I just saw that timestart 145 means 1 hour and 45 minutes. This is about the worst way to store datetime information possible. You want another calculation then:

```
select dateadd(minute, timestart / 100 * 60 + timestart % 100, mydate) from mytable;
```

But what you really should do is fix your data model and make your date and obfuscated time one datetime column. (Well, maybe this is exactly what you are in the process of doing just now :-)

Comment: so if i will do a date range query. it would be  Select * from mytable where (dateadd(minute,[timestart],[mydate]) between '2019-11-01 00:00' and '2019-11-02 06:00)

Comment: Yes. This would include '2019-11-02 06:00:00,0000', but exclude '2019-11-02 06:00:00,0001'. It's more typical to exclude the upper bound altogether: `where dateadd(minute,[timestart],[mydate]) >= '2019-11-01 00:00' dateadd(minute,[timestart],[mydate]) < '2019-11-02 06:00)`.

Comment: i'll get back to you tomorrow sir Thorsten. thanks in advance.

Comment: by the way sir Thorsten, why cant i make a query with  <=. let say if i have "where dateadd(minute,[timestart],[mydate]) >= '2019-11-01 00:00' dateadd(minute,[timestart],[mydate]) < '2019-11-02 06:00)" the value with '2019-11-02 06:00' cannot be include

Comment: You *can* use `BETWEEN` or `<=`. All I was saying is that it's untypical to include the millisecond `2019-11-02 06:00:00,0000`, but not `2019-11-02 06:00:00,0001`. One would usually either include the minute `2019-11-02 06:00` with all its fractional parts or exclude it. The same thing is more obvious at midnight: Why include the first millisecond of the next day, but exclude the second millisecond? One would rather exclude the whole day.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a time, then add minutes to the value:

```
select convert(time, dateadd(minute, (timecol / 100) + timecol % 60, 0))
```

Of course, you can just add this to `mydate` column:

```
select dateadd(minute, (timecol / 100) + timecol % 60, mydate)
```

Comment: im sorry. i want to combine MyDate and int as my date and time like 2019-11-01 00:06